# How to tell EF core two models use the same table?

Tags: c#, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.2

I'm migrating a classic SQL database to EF core 2.2 and I'm facing a problem.
I'm not new to EF but I don't see how to do this...

Here is the problem, I have a table `Users`, a table `Groups`, and a table `Members`. Members are users composing Groups. I simplified models and kept only the keys :

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Group> Groups { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [Key]
    public int GroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(GroupId))]
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Member> Members { get; set; }
}
```

In classic SQL I can join tables by key, but how can I "jump" from `Users` to `Groups` like `User.Groups` ?

Comment: https://www.bilyachat.com/blog/how-to-upgrade-entityframework-to-core

Comment: Many to many is a bit different in EFcore

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat It's not a many to many, I have done this on another tables and it works fine : `modelBuilder.Entity<UserSeason>().HasKey(x => new { x.UserId, x.SeasonId });
modelBuilder.Entity<UserSeason>().HasOne(x => x.Season).WithMany(x => x.Users).HasForeignKey(x => x.SeasonId);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserSeason>().HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.Seasons).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
modelBuilder.Entity<UserSeason>().ToTable("UserSeasons");`

Answer (score 0):

User already has a groups why do you need to include the group into Member? is not just having a user enough? If you need to read Members from DB then you can read them and use "Include" method to add User or Groups in your case. Something like this will do the job:

```
   var result = db.Members
                .Include(m => m.Groups)
                .Include(m => m.User)
```

Comment: Member has some properties specific to the group associated, like the registration date, the user role, etc. The DTO of Member extends User. So Groups have a collection of members, but a user is registered in many groups

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolved this by another way :

```
User.Groups = context.Groups.Where(g => g.Members.Any(m => m.UserId == x.Id)).Select(g => new GenericData
{
    Id = g.Id,
    Tag = g.Tag,
    Label = g.Name,
    Flag = g.Flag
}).ToList()
```

Where `x` is the db user

It works like this, but if someone could say me how to do this like I wanted at start, I'm curious to know it :)